# Setvalue Display the first value that is not Zero

Tags: reporting-services

I use microsoft sql server report builder.
I have a big sql query for the Presentation of my Report. i want to assign the output of one of  the Columns to a textbox. the txbox should be displayed the first value of the table which is not zero.

I tried that First(Fields!name.Value, "V_Tabelle") .but if the first value is null, the textbox remains empty
I tried that IIf(IsNothing(Fields!name.Value), "null", Fields!name.Value) , but i am receiving an error. field references outside a data area must be included in aggregate functions that specify a dataset area.

```
 First(Fields!name.Value, "V_Tabelle")
IIf(IsNothing(Fields!name.Value), "null", Fields!name.Value)
```

The value expression for the text field "Status6" refers directly to the field "name" without specifying a dataset aggregate. If the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside a data area must be included in aggregate functions that specify a dataset area.

Answer (score 1):

This way it checks if the first value is `null`, is this the case the text `Empty` will be displayed.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!YourField.Value, "DataSet1") = Nothing, 
     "Empty", 
     First(Fields!YourField.Value, "DataSet1")
     )
```